# Default page starting point

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have few divs set next to each other making a horizontal scrolling page.

Currently I am using animate scrollLeft to navigate through the div's but I want when you visit the site to begin from the middle.

The divs are like this:

## Div1   #Div2   #Div3   #Div4   #Div5

and I want viewers to start from #Div3.

How can I achieve that? I tried scrollLeft(); but didn't work.

Comment: Works for me when used like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/8yD8c/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: $('#section2').offset().left});
```

Also set the body to visibility:hidden so in case of lag it doesn't display the page.

After you call the animation set the content visibility to visible.

Example:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: $('#div3').offset().left});
$('html, body').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).delay(400).animate({opacity: 1.0});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery scrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), read more about it here: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Basically you'll need to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
  ...
  $.scrollTo($('#Div4'));
});
```

Comment: I am aware of that. I am not willing to use a plugin. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the div's ID and a fragment identifier in the URL.

```
<div id="divIWantToBeScrolledTo">...</div>
```

Then in the URL

```
http://www.example.com/myPage#divIWantToBeScrolledTo
```

Comment: but that only works if that is the urk being visited. what if they are coming straight from `example.com` and should be scrolled there anyway

Comment: you can use `scrollIntoView()` once the page has loaded: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView